# How to make a bandpass filter in the pan-tompkins algorithm but without using scipy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

So I'm currently doing an assignment in biomedical signal processing and we have to make a QRS detection code for detecting the QRS Complex in an ECG signal (electrocardiograph signal). The problem is that we have to make the equations from scratch. By from scratch, I mean without using the python SCIPY LIBRARY. Which means I can't just put a filtfilt function or  a butter() function into my signal.

Now below I have my current progress of my code, It follows this algorithm (the pan tompkins one)
[pan tompkins algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMdZA.png)

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import math


#declare variables to be put into use
#fs= 1kHz
fs = 1000
M = 15 #total number of orders/sequence

#Read data and plot the original signal
#Read ecg data and do slicing process on the ecg column 
ecg_data = np.loadtxt('ecg_data1.txt', dtype='float')[:,1]
n_data = np.loadtxt('ecg_data1.txt', dtype='float')[:,0]
N = len(n_data)
#make N into an array to be plotted, from 0 to 5000
n = np.arange(0,N)

#Plotting signals and styling using matplotlib
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.title("Original ECG Signal with N=5000", font="times new roman", size=25)
plt.plot(n,ecg_data, color='blue')
plt.show()

#Pre-filtering stage 
#Which includes a (MAV)
#Moving Average Filter


y1 = np.zeros(10000) #y1 variable for forward MAV
y2 = np.zeros(10000) #y2 variable for backward MAV
M = 15 #total number of orders/sequence
x = np.zeros(10000)
#We use 10000 since the backward signal equation creates an index out of range error
for i in range(N):
    x[i] = ecg_data[i]

#-----------------------Zero Lag Filtering-----------------------------#
#forward MAV
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        y1[i] += x[i-j]
    
    y1[i] = y1[i]/M
    
#backward MAV
for i in range(N-1, -1, -1):
    for j in range(M):
        y2[i] += y1[i+j]
    y2[i] = y2[i]/M

#Plotting Forward 
plt.figure(figsize=(30,8))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.title("Forward MAV ECG Signal Output",font="times new roman", size=25)
plt.plot(n, y1[n], color ='red')


#Plotting Backward MAV
plt.figure(figsize=(30,8))
plt.subplot(1,2,2)  
plt.title("Backward MAV ECG Signal Output",font="times new roman", size=25)
plt.plot(n, y2[n], color='orange')
plt.show()

#Signal Plotting Comparison Part
#In this cell we are plotting a comparison with original signal, mav forward & backward
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,8))
ax.plot(n, x[n], linewidth=1, color='blue', label='Original')
ax.plot(n, y1[n], linewidth=1, color='red', label='Forward')
ax.plot(n, y2[n], linewidth=1, color='orange', label='Backward')
ax.set_title("Original Signal-MAV Forward, MAV-Backward Comparison",font="times new roman", size=25)
fig.tight_layout()
ax.legend(fontsize=20)
plt.show()


#---------------------------Segmentation Part--------------------------------#
fs = 1000
fc = 21
fh = 7
fl = 14

ohm_cutoff = 2*np.pi*fc/fs
ohm_h = 2*np.pi*fh/fs
ohm_l = 2*np.pi*fl/fs
#Impulse Response
hi = np.zeros(2*M+1)
m = np.arange(-M, M+1)
cont = 0
pre_filtered_signal = y2[n]
#Frequency Response
d = np.arange(-180, 181)
xf = np.zeros(10000)


for i in d:
    cont = 0
    omh = 2*np.pi/360
    
    for j in range(1,M+1)
       cont += hi[j]*np.cos(j*ohm)
    xf[i] = hi[0] + 2*cont
    

def lowpass_filter():
    for i in m:
        hi[i] = ohm_cutoff/np.pi
lowpass_filter()


def highpass_filter():
    for i in m:
        hi[i] = (np.pi-ohm_cutoff)/np.pi
highpass_filter()
        
        
plt.figure(figsize=(25,8))        
plt.plot(pre_filtered_signal)
plt.show()
```

Now the problem is I've already plotted my signal, and applied both a forward and backward MAV signal. But the part where I'm stuck at is the bandpass filter part where i gotta apply a highpass filter and a lowpass filter. I roughly know how to apply the squaring and the derivative function (just using numpy). So yeah I'm confused on how to do it without scipy because every tutorial i find everywhere on the internet is doing this using scipy module.
Here's my current progress of the signal plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbpgC.png)

Comment: scipy is open source and there links to the source in the documentation. Have you tried looking at that to see how scipy does it? I bet it will give you a *leg up*.

Comment: hmm I haven't looked at it much really